# Finding Orders in my Dictionary using customer name

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I need to look up orders in the dictionary by using name, but can't figure how to use the name (string) to find the matching order because the value of the dictionary is object Order.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Public Shared orders As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Order)

Private Sub btnFindName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindName.Click

    Dim orderFound As Boolean

    Dim name As String = txtFindName.Text

    For Each order In orders

        If order.Value = name Then

            orderFound = True
            Return

        End If

    Next
    If Not orderFound Then
        errProvider.SetError(txtFindName, "No order found with that name.")
        txtFindName.Focus()
        Return

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate through Orders, you are getting a [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) of Integer, Order.  Assuming your Order class has a Name property:

```
Public Class Order
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

You would adjust like so:

```
For Each Order As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Order) In orders

    If Order.Value.Name = name Then

        orderFound = True
        Return

    End If

Next
```

And if you want to be nice to your users don't make it case sensitive:

```
If Order.Value.Name.ToUpper() = name.ToUpper() Then
```